# Are mumps strings mutated in a call to the Piece function?

Tags: mumps

Example:

```
s str="10/1/96"
s $P(str,"/",2)=2"
w !,str
```

**Output:** 10/2/96

1. In the call to piece function, does the value at index 4, ***1***, change to ***2***?
2. Or is a new string created with the value of ***10/2/96*** and copied into str.

Comment: In your mind, what would the difference be? Note that there's no such thing as a reference type (or honestly, types at all) in ANSI mumps. The piece/set is atomic, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @yhyrcanus I'm not asking for atomicity, I'm asking if strings are mutable.  There is a big difference between editing a string in-place vs new &copy.  In-place is done in constant time, vs making a new string and copying it over requires N complexity, where N is the length of the new string to copy over.

Comment: If it was a global set, it might be more performant to copy, modify, write, rather than writing in place even if the complexity is higher. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't believe the standard says specifically how a mumps environment implements anything. If you're worried about performance on set piece, don't. It's faster than anything you can implement to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Set $P[IECE] and Set $E[XTRACT] modify the string in place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  May I ask where you found this?  I couldn't find it in documentation after looking for it?

Comment: This is the M 95 and earlier Standards link: http://71.174.62.16/Demo/AnnoStd?Frame=Main&Edition=1977&Page=a108048#Def_0005. Is this what you are looking for? M has no concept of "immutable" strings like Java. All strings are mutable, as in most scripting languages.